# Open pdf link in external browser

Tags: android, iframe, cordova

I have an app for Android made in PhoneGap that basically has an iframe the size of the whole screen with a mobile website.

That website has some links to pdf files to download. The link in the website is like this:

```
<a href="doc.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

How can I get the app to open an external browser with the pdf link?

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m, at line 107, there is the 'shouldStartLoadWithRequest' method.  You can add the following to force URLs to open in the external browser:

```
NSURL *url = [request URL];
// Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
// Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
} else {
    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}
```

You could modify this to verify that there is a ".pdf" present in the URL instead of checking to see if it starts with "http" or "https" if you only want the pdfs to open externally.

See http://www.midnightryder.com/technology-blog/a-quick-phonegap-fix-for-http-https-external-browser-launch-problem for more information.

Comment: That's the ios trick, I need the one for android. Do you have some info on that one?

Comment: For that, the Phonegap code is jar'd, so your best bet AFAIK is to pull the source, modify and build a custom Phonegap jar.  In a bit, I'll look into it.  Also, have you looked at opening the links in a childbrowser?

Comment: How do I get that exact link to open in a childbrowser? That could be a great solution!